# How to group_by chinese character in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

[image]

I would like to group these column by name of the poster?
Can anybody help!
Thank you!

Comment: Please avoid posting images or screenshots. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and post

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).